# jQuery only seems to be working in Layout.cshtml

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net-5

I am currently working on the basics of a .NET C# Razor page application running the following:

- Razor pages
- .NET 5/C#
- jQuery v3.5.1
- Bootstrap v4.3.1

My current issue is that jQuery (and plain JS) are only working in the Layout.cshtml file, I have tried the following:

1. Script tags in the head of _layout.cshtml
2. Script tags at the bottom of the body of _layout.cshtml
3. Wrapping the jQuery in @section scripts{}

At this stage I am fairly sure it is just a case of, it needs to be setup in a very particular way in .NET5, but I really have no more clues

**Bottom of _Layout.cshtml**

```
    </header>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    @RenderSection("Head", required: false);
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false);

</body>
</html>
```

**Bottom of the index.cshtml file**

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".btn-reply").click(function (event) {
                alert("it works");
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: If you add  <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script> into head section, it will work properly..

Comment: @Kaan that was one of the first things I tried, I had seen a few similar comments of people saying they thought the script tags should be in the head

Comment: You *don't* need (or necessarily want) your script tags in the `<head>`.  There's plenty of discussion about this but simply moving it into the head would not suddenly make everything else work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Rather frustratingly this turned out not to be anything JS related at all, in actually fact this was down to main div with the class of row having a z-index of -1, no idea how this came to be, I don’t recal having set this, but if I did I whole apologise to anyone who took the time to read this.